# paste / paste simple in IDEs (pycharm)

Tags: pycharm, shortcut, paste

In pycharm and other IDE's keymaps there are two different "Paste" options: "paste" and "paste simple".
In my Pycharm windows version, the default Ctrl + V shortcut activates the "paste" option which exhibit a strange behavior where the copied value is always pasted at the beginning of the selected line, making impossible to paste code where the user needs it. I had to change the keymap inside settings to have Ctrl+V to activate "simple paste" and to inactivate the default "paste" shortcut to have a normal paste behavior.
Has anyone an idea why are there 2 different features of "paste"? What is it good for?